# Flask LoginManager not calling correct Login_View

Tags: flask, loginview

I have a very strange behavior with my Flask App.

The app is based on the one from Miguel Grinberg's [tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

So I have defined

```
lm.login_view = 'login'
```

I also have my view to it:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
##@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    print "Login started"
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():
        print "first test passed"
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print "submit done"
        session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
        return oid.try_login(form.openid.data, ask_for=['nickname', 'email'])
    print "calling login"
    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form,
                           providers=app.config['OPENID_PROVIDERS'])
```

But it does not get triggered.
The other views work as desired so I inserted some prints in order to see what Flask is doing but here is no print-out at all.

The funny thin is that I always get this standard output but I have nowheredefined that html:

[image: Screenshot of website]

I also used a base-layout with bootstrap included but this looks very naked to me.

I had also renamed the **view** and **the lm.login_view** but it was not fired at all.

Do you have any idea where I can search for it or find it???

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem that my login view has not been triggered:

```
Map([<Rule '/register' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> register>,
 <Rule '/logout' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> security.logout>,
 <Rule '/login' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> security.login>,
 <Rule '/index' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> index>,
 <Rule '/login' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> login>,
 <Rule '/' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> index>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>,
 <Rule '/index/<page>' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> index>])
```

As you can see I had 2 rules for login and the first was pointing to security.login.
Now I found out that this came from importing the security extension of flask.